# Dynamic Key Allocation: from csv file to linked list

Tags: c, txt

For this code, we load the txt file via OPEN function and the other functions just work with the linked list loaded. Only SAVE overwrites the actual the txt file using the current state of the linked list.

The data in the file looks like this:

```
ID  Name
10009   popo
9213    abc
10017   Aft Hosp Dr
10018   Outram Pk Stn Exit 6/SGH
10021   Blk 3
10041   Bef Kampong Bahru Ter
10049   Opp Kampong Bahru Ter
10051   Blk 149
10059   abc
10069   Opp Blk 140
10071   Blk 111
10079   Blk 201
10081   Opp Blk 120
```

Everything works well but I have trouble implementing a feature for the INSERT. It should skip the first line in the code as the first line is just the headers. It also needs to go through all the other lines as not all keys (unique ID) are the same number of digits. What it needs to do is it must go through all keys if it finds out that the keys are 4 and 5 digits and integer type, the insert will only allow 4 and 5 digit keys which are integer type to be inserted. It needs to be dynamic as I will work with other txt files and the key data type and lengths are always changing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_KEY 10
#define MAX_VALUE 60
#define MAX_COMMAND 80
#define MAX_FILENAME 30

// Structure to represent a single record
typedef struct RecordNode {
    char *Key;              // A pointer to a character string representing the key
    char *Value;            // A pointer to a character string representing the value
    struct RecordNode *next; // A pointer to the next record in the linked list
} RecordNode;

// Function Prototype
int openDatabase(const char *filename, RecordNode **records, int *numRecords);
int saveDatabase(const char *filename, RecordNode *records, int numRecords);
void showAllRecords(RecordNode *records, int numRecords);
int insertRecord(RecordNode **records, int *numRecords, const char *Key, const char *Value);
void searchRecord(RecordNode *records, const char *Key);
void updateRecord(RecordNode *records, const char *Key, const char *Value);
void deleteRecord(RecordNode **records, int *numRecords, const char *Key);

// Main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    RecordNode *records = NULL; // Head of the linked list
    int numRecords = 0;
    char command[MAX_COMMAND];
    char filename[MAX_FILENAME] = ""; // Initialize the filename
    char openFilename[45];
    char RecordKey[MAX_KEY];
    char RecordValue[MAX_VALUE];

    if (argc > 1) {
        strncpy(filename, argv[1], sizeof(filename) - 1);
    }

    while (1) {
        printf("\nAVAILABLE COMMANDS:\n");
        printf("Show all records: \tSHOW ALL\n");
        printf("Add a new record \tINSERT <Key> <Value>\n");
        printf("Search for a record: \tQUERY <Key>\n");
        printf("Update a record: \tUPDATE <Key> <Value>\n");
        printf("Delete a record: \tDELETE <Key>\n");        
        printf("Open an existing file: \tOPEN <Filename>\n");
        printf("Save the database: \tSAVE <Filename>\n");
        printf("Exit the program: \tEXIT\n");
        printf("\nEnter a command: ");
        fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);

        size_t len = strlen(command);
        if (len > 0 && command[len - 1] == '\n') {
            command[len - 1] = '\0'; // Remove the newline character and replacing with \0
        }
        else {// Handle the case where the command is too long for the buffer, to prevent buffer overflow        
            int c;
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); //Clear input buffer where getchar will grab anything NOT '\n' & 'EOF'

            printf("Error: Command is too long. Please enter a shorter command.\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (strcmp(command, "SHOW ALL") == 0) {
            showAllRecords(records, numRecords);
        } 
        else if (strncmp(command, "INSERT", 6) == 0) {            
            if (sscanf(command + 6, " %s %[^\n]", RecordKey, RecordValue) == 2) {
                insertRecord(&records, &numRecords, RecordKey, RecordValue);
            } 
            else {
                printf("Invalid command. Please use the format: INSERT <Key> <Value>\n");
            }
        } 
        else if (strncmp(command, "QUERY", 5) == 0) {
            if (sscanf(command + 5, " %s", RecordKey) == 1) {
                searchRecord(records, RecordKey);
            } 
            else {
                printf("Invalid command. Please use the format: QUERY <Key>\n");
            }
        } 
        else if (strncmp(command, "UPDATE", 6) == 0) {
            if (sscanf(command + 6, " %s %[^\n]", RecordKey, RecordValue) == 2) {
                updateRecord(records, RecordKey, RecordValue);
            } 
            else {
                printf("Invalid command. Please use the format: UPDATE <Key> <Value>\n");
            }
        } 
        else if (strncmp(command, "DELETE", 6) == 0) {
            if (sscanf(command + 6, " %s", RecordKey) == 1) {
                deleteRecord(&records, &numRecords, RecordKey);
            } 
            else {
                printf("Invalid command. Please use the format: DELETE <Key>\n");
            }
        } 
        else if (strncmp(command, "SAVE", 4) == 0) {
            if (strlen(filename) == 0) {
                printf("Error: No filename specified. Please use the format: SAVE <filename>\n");
            } 
            else if (strcmp(command + 5, filename) == 0)
            {
                saveDatabase(filename, records, numRecords);
            }            
            else {
                printf("Error: File not found. Unable to save file.\n");
            }
        } 
        else if (strncmp(command, "OPEN", 4) == 0) {
            if (sscanf(command + 5, " %s", openFilename) == 1) {
                if (openDatabase(openFilename, &records, &numRecords)) {
                    strncpy(filename, openFilename, sizeof(filename) - 1);
                }
            } 
            else {
                printf("Invalid command. Please use the format: OPEN <filename>\n");
            }
        } 
        else if (strcmp(command, "EXIT") == 0) {
            // Free allocated memory for records
            while (records != NULL) {
                RecordNode *temp = records;
                records = records->next;
                free(temp->Key);
                free(temp->Value);
                free(temp);
            }
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            printf("Invalid command. Please enter a valid command.\n");
        }
    }

    // Free allocated memory for records
    while (records != NULL) {
        RecordNode *temp = records;
        records = records->next;
        free(temp->Key);
        free(temp->Value);
        free(temp);
    }

    return 0;
}

// Function to open and read a database file
int openDatabase(const char *filename, RecordNode **records, int *numRecords) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r"); // Open the file for reading
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: File not found.\n");
        return 0; // Return an error code (0) if the file can't be opened
    }

    // Clear the existing records (if any)
    while (*records != NULL) {
        RecordNode *temp = *records;
        *records = (*records)->next;
        free(temp->Key);
        free(temp->Value);
        free(temp);
    }

    *numRecords = 0; // Initialize the number of records
    *records = NULL; // Initialize the linked list

    char key[MAX_KEY];
    char *value;
    RecordNode *current = NULL;

    // Read records from the file and create a linked list
    while (fscanf(file, "%s", key) != EOF) {
        value = (char *)calloc(MAX_VALUE, sizeof(char)); // Allocate memory for the value
        fscanf(file, " %[^\n]", value);
        RecordNode *newNode = (RecordNode *)calloc(1, sizeof(RecordNode)); // Create a new record node
        newNode->Key = strdup(key); // Copy the key into the node
        newNode->Value = value;     // Set the value pointer
        newNode->next = NULL;      // Initialize the next pointer

        if (*records == NULL) {
            *records = newNode; // Set the head of the linked list
            current = newNode;
        } 
        else {
            current->next = newNode; // Add the new node to the end of the list
            current = newNode;
        }

        (*numRecords)++; // Increment the record count
    }

    fclose(file); // Close the file
    printf("Database opened from %s. %d records found.\n", filename, *numRecords-1);
    return 1; // Return a success code (1)
}

// Function to save data from the linked list to the database file
int saveDatabase(const char *filename, RecordNode *records, int numRecords) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w"); // should not be opening file=========================================warning
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Unable to open the file for writing.\n");
        return 0; // Return an error code (0) if the file can't be opened
    }

    RecordNode *current = records;
    // Write records from the linked list to the file
    while (current != NULL) {
        fprintf(file, "%s %s\n", current->Key, current->Value);
        current = current->next;
    }

    fclose(file); // Close the file
    printf("Database saved to %s.\n", filename);
    return 1; // Return a success code (1)
}

// Function to show all records from the linked list
void showAllRecords(RecordNode *records, int numRecords) {
    printf("There are in total %d records found:\n", numRecords-1);
    RecordNode *current = records;
    int i = 0;
    // Display all records in the linked list, starting from the second record
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (i > 0) {
            printf("%s %s\n", current->Key, current->Value);
        }
        current = current->next;
        i++;
    }
}

// Function to insert a new record into the linked list
int insertRecord(RecordNode **records, int *numRecords, const char *Key, const char *Value) {
    RecordNode *current = *records;

    // Check if the record already exists in the database
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->Key, Key) == 0) {
            printf("The record with Key=%s already exists in the database.\n", Key);
            return 0; // Return an error code (0) if the record already exists
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    // Insert a new record at the bottom (end) of the linked list
    RecordNode *newNode = (RecordNode *)malloc(sizeof(RecordNode)); // Create a new record node
    newNode->Key = strdup(Key); // Copy the key into the node
    newNode->Value = strdup(Value); // Set the value pointer
    newNode->next = NULL; // Initialize the next pointer

    if (*records == NULL) {
        *records = newNode; // Set the head of the linked list
    } 
    else {
        current = *records;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newNode; // Add the new node to the end of the list
    }

    (*numRecords)++; // Increment the record count
    printf("A new record of Key=%s, Value=%s is successfully inserted.\n", Key, Value);
    return 1; // Return a success code (1)
}

// Function to search for a record in the linked list
void searchRecord(RecordNode *records, const char *Key) {
    RecordNode *current = records;

    // Search for the record with the given key
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->Key, Key) == 0) {
            printf("A record of Key=%s, Value=%s is found in the database.\n", Key, current->Value);
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    printf("There is no record with Key=%s found in the database.\n", Key);
}

// Function to update a record in the linked list
void updateRecord(RecordNode *records, const char *Key, const char *Value) {
    RecordNode *current = records;

    // Search for the record with the given key
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->Key, Key) == 0) {
            free(current->Value); // Free the old value
            current->Value = strdup(Value); // Set the new value
            printf("The value for the record of Key=%s is successfully updated.\n", Key);
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    printf("There is no record with Key=%s found in the database.\n", Key);
}

// Function to delete a record from the linked list
void deleteRecord(RecordNode **records, int *numRecords, const char *Key) {
    RecordNode *current = *records;
    RecordNode *prev = NULL;

    // Search for the record with the given key
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->Key, Key) == 0) {
            if (prev == NULL) {
                *records = current->next; // Update the head of the linked list
            } 
            else {
                prev->next = current->next; // Remove the current node from the list
            }
            free(current->Key);
            free(current->Value);
            free(current);
            (*numRecords)--; // Decrement the record count
            printf("The record of Key=%s is successfully deleted.\n", Key);
            return;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    printf("There is no record with Key=%s found in the database.\n", Key);
}
```

I have tried adjusting the #define to restrict the quantity of characters the user can input but it had no effect

Comment: This is a lot of code. Can you narrow down specifically what you're trying to do and what is not working?

Comment: @Retired Ninja I did!

"Everything works well but I have trouble implementing a feature for the INSERT." This line onwards

Comment: You did not. What are the exact commands someone would need to type in order to duplicate the issue? Is the snippet of the file shown enough to duplicate it? How would someone know if it was working correctly or not?

Comment: @wrwerwerewwerr, Use of `"%s"` and `" %[^\n]"` without a _width_ limit is risky code.  Use a width like `"%9s"` when reading.

Comment: @wrwerwerewwerr `strncpy(filename, argv[1], sizeof(filename) - 1);` risk forming a non-string in `filename`.

Comment: @wrwerwerewwerr As `strdup()` is not a standard C library function, yet, are you missing a prototype?

Comment: The code is problematic at it is but you can go this way. It is a common one, If your problem is just wih the headers insert a call to `fgets` before entering the `while` loop around line 265. This is in order to consume the first line

Comment: @arfneto Mixing `fgets()` with `fscanf()` is problematic as the first consume trailing `'\n'` and the 2nd usually does not.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it makes no difference, it is just the matter of discarding the 1st line. This is the question. There is no mixing: there is only one first line.

Comment: test with something like this: fgets(key, 2, file); while (fscanf(file, "%s", key) != EOF)..

Comment: `key[0] = (char) fgetc(file);` would do the same. You just need to consume input until the end of the first line. You could also consider creating a real `Linked List` and putting the field names from the 1st line in the list's metadata to have the field names to use in `SHOW ALL`

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

For discarding the first line you need no more than read until the `\n`, and as `stdio` is line buffered you can use a simple call to `fgetc` or `fgets`. It makes no difference.

```
    fgets(key, 1, file);

    // or 

    key[0] = (char) fgetc(file);
```